# Como saber si una Web Service Esta Disponible

Tags: asp.net, webservice

Buenas tardes, 
quisiera poder verificar si una web service esta disponible, así como se haría un ping a una url, tengo este metodo, pero se cae al poner la url de alguna web service.

```
        Ping pings = new Ping();
        int timeout = 10;

        if (pings.Send("http://www.sunat.gob.pe", timeout).Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exito");

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

prueba lo siguiente:

```
        var url = "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx";

        try
        {
            var myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            var response = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Debug.Write(string.Format("{0} Disponible", url));
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Write(string.Format("{0} Status: {1}", url, response.StatusDescription));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Write(string.Format("{0} No Disponible: {1}", url, ex.Message));
        }
```